# Node Js: Call async await within map not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await

I'm creating a tinder clone. Im currently creating the match/post request in my backend. Within the post request itself it calls a separate `function` named `match`. This is called after the current user as liked or disliked another account. Basically all I need this function to do is loop through that account's likes to see if it matches the current users id. As I am using MongoDB I need to be able to make use of `async await` to interact with my database. However the `function` never runs past the `if` statement. I'm thinking it has something to do with calling an `async function` within `.map()`. However I am a bit stumped on how to progress further.

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const multer = require('multer');

const User = require("../models/userSchema");

const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.jpg')
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }) 

function asyncHandler(callback) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}

function match (match, user) {
  console.log("Starting to match")

  const currentUser = user;

  console.log(currentUser._id)

  match.likes.map((person) => {

      return async( req, res, next) => {

        console.log(person._id, 'Person id')
        console.log(currentUser._id, 'Current user id')

        if (person.likes._id === currentUser._id) {
        
        console.log("Worked")

        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectID(currentUser._id) }, { $push: { matches: match } });
  
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: match._id },{ $push: { matches: currentUser } });
  
        res.json({ message: "You got a match!" }).end();
      }  
    }
  });
};


/*
Adds matches to the user 
*/

router.patch( "/user/match/:id", authenticateUser, asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

  const errors = validationResult(req);

  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const errorMessages = errors.array().map((error) => error.msg);
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errorMessages });
  }

  const updateObject = req.body.likes;
  console.log(updateObject)

  const likedUser = await User.findOne({ _id: updateObject });


  if (updateObject) {

    await User.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: req.params.id }, { $push: { likes: updateObject } });
    console.log("Getting ready to match")
    match(likedUser, user)

  } else {

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $push: { dislikes: updateObject } },

      function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          return res.json({ success: false, message: err.message });
        }

        res.json({ updateObject });

        return res.status(204).end();

      }
    );
  }

})
);
```

```
   {
      likes: [Array],
      dislikes: [],
      _id: '60bcfe5191694b0981439707',
      firstName: 'Jon',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      emailAddress: 'JonDoe@gmail.com',
      password: '$2a$10$cOt9PcLUd7HdwzYjhBAov.OWVGQUbBVVpR2SiVSXghFWaJfX88bSm',
      gender: 'Male',
      sexualPreference: 'Straight',
      age: 26,
      description: 'Hello my name is Jon',
      path: 'uploads/1622998609804.jpg',
      matches: [],
      __v: 0
    }

The likes array is an array of objects composed like this user object.
```

Comment: "*`match.likes.map((person) => { return async( req, res, next) => { … } })`*" creates an array of async functions, then does nothing with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use `async`-`await` inside array functions like `forEach()`, `map()`.
`forEach()` expects a synchronous function and even when we use `async`/`await` inside, it just returns multiple promises but not in sequential order.

Solution:

1. Either use for of loop which does your work sequentially.
2. If you want to use `Array.map()` then put it inside `Promise.all()` so that it does your task in parallel.

Example:

```js
await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
  // your code here....
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to replicate without seeing the data, but I wouldn't recommend using `.map` in this situation, as you're not returning anything and they don't work well with asynchronous code. I'd use a recursive function like this...

I've used a placeholder fetch request instead of a DB update, but the principle is the same...

```
const recursive = async (matches, user, run = 0) => {
    if (run > matches.length) return
    console.log(run)
    if (matches[run] === user+1) {
        
      await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
      
      return recursive(matches, user, run +1)
    } 
    else return recursive(matches, user, run +1)
  }
```

Input...

```
recursive([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
```

Output...

```
0
1
2
{userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false}
3
4
```

The function won't call itself until the last iteration has finished and it will await for the api call to return something before finishing.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding, I have updated the question to include the data as requested.